# My code doesnt execute the printf statement after the while statement

Tags: c

Given two integers representing the starting and ending values of a range of numbers and two
additional integers representing potential factors of values within the range, create a total by adding each
integer in the range that is a m
multiple of exactly one of the factors and subtracting each integer in the
range that is a multiple of both factors.

### This is my code. I am trying to run it. It compiles and takes in all the info but does not print the total! Please Help!

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <math.h>

        //Factor Declarations
        int getStart(); //recieves starting range value from user
        int getEnd(int start); //recieves ending range value from user
        int getFirst(); //recieves first factor from user
        int getSecond(int *first); //recieves second factor from user


        int main (void)
        {
          //Local Declarations
          int start; //starting range
          int end; //ending range
          int first; //first factor
          int second; // second factor
          int x;
          int y;
          int total = 0;

          //Executable Statements
          start = getStart();
          end = getEnd(start);
          first = getFirst();
          second = getSecond(&first);
          x = start;
          y = first * second;

          while (x <= end)
          {  if ((x % first == 0 || x % second == 0) && (x % y != 0))
            {
            total += x;}
          else if (x % y == 0)
               total -= x;

     x++;}

        printf("\nTotal: %d", total);
        return 0;
    }


    /******************************************************************************
     *  * Function:    getStart
     *   * Description: Gets user input for starting range, ensures good value
     *    * Parameters:
     *     * Return:      num, ending value
     *      ******************************************************************************/
    int getStart()
    {
      int num;

      do
      {
        printf("\nEnter starting range value: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if(num <= 0)
        {
          printf("Error! Starting value must be greater than zero!\n");
        }
      } while(num <= 0);

      return num;
    }

/******************************************************************************
 *  * Function:    getEnd
 *   * Description: Gets ending range value from user, ensures value is lager than starting value
 *    * Parameters:  start, int, starting value
 *     * Return:      num, ending value
 *      ******************************************************************************/
int getEnd(int start)
{
  int num;

  do
  {
    printf("Enter ending range value: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if(num <= start)
    {
      printf("Error! Ending value must be greater than the starting value!\n");
    }
  } while(num <= start);

  return num;
}

/******************************************************************************
 *  * Function:    <function name>
 *   * Description: <brief description of what the function does>
 *    * Parameters:  <variable1 name, data type, and description>
 *     *              <variable2 name, data type, and description>
 *      * Return:      <data type and description>
 *       ******************************************************************************/
int getFirst()
{
  int num;

  do
  {
    printf("Enter first factor: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if(num <= 0)
    {
      printf("Error! Factors must be positive!\n");
    }
  } while(num <= 0);

  return num;
}
/******************************************************************************
 * * Function:    <function name>
 * * Description: <brief description of what the function does>
 * * Parameters:  <variable1 name, data type, and description>
 * *              <variable2 name, data type, and description>
 * * Return:      <data type and description>
 * ******************************************************************************/
int getSecond(int *first)
{
  int num;

  do
  {
    printf("Enter second factor: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if(num <= 0)
    {
      printf("Error! Factors must be positive!\n");
    }

    if(num == *first)
    {
      printf("Error! The values of the two multiples cannot be the same!\n");
      *first = getFirst();
      num = getSecond(first);
    }
  } while(num <= 0 || num == *first);

  return num;
}
```

Comment: `while (x <= end);` <=== remove semi-colon. Enable higher warning levels on your compiler. `clang` will report "While loop has empty body", for example, with appropriately high warnings enabled.

Comment: Sorry, but that is terrible formatting!

Comment: @FiddlingBits it seems intnded but it's quite unreadable, I thought it was just me, and sometimes people would fight over that.

Comment: Hey guys, so i tried that out and the code started to print the print statement. But now the code is giving me the wrong total. I mean for example if I input 5 as the start, 15 as the end, and then 2 and 3 as the factors I get the total as 38139. So the right answer is just 38. and then if run the code again the total increases by 1 i mean it would give me 38140. I have tried many numbers and this is the same with every one of them. The correct answer is in there but there are way more digits!

Answer (score 4):

Of course it doesn't, because there is no way to end the `while()` loop in your code, you don't change `x` nor `end` inside the loop.

Perhaps you mean

```
while (total <= end)
```

Comment: @TalhaAhmedKhan also listen to `WhozCraig`'s comment, remove the semicolon.